# Can't click in applications / windows

Tags: unity, mouse

Just installed Ubuntu today, first time using it. I noticed during installation that on and off I couldn't click the mouse and had to use tab and enter to select things. I could always move the mouse though.

Once I got it installed and up and running it persisted. When I am just on the desktop I can click stuff but as soon as I open anything, a file explorer, firefox, settings, whatever - mouse clicks no longer work. It's almost as though the active window is in the background but not really.

I've tried alt-tab, log out and in, reboot, etc. I've made sure everything was up to date. Also once I open something I now cannot click on the desktop either. Only when nothing else is open or showing can I click on the desktop / menu bar icons.

I've looked this up for the past 2 hours online and all I can find is other people with the same problem and no working solution given. It's completely unusable.

Using Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it's own drive, Windows 10 is also installed for this desktop but on a different drive. Mouse is Mad Catz MMO 7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my mouse, the Mad Catz MMO 7.

The fix was to create "xorg.conf" in /etc/X11 and then edit it to contain:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse|M.M.O.7"
MatchIsPointer "true"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option    "Buttons" "24"
Option    "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 10 11 12 0 0 0 16 17 7 6 0 0 0 0 0" 
Option    "AutoReleaseButtons" "20 21 22 23 24" 
Option    "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

Reboot and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue and it was also my mouse. It kept holding the left-mouse button and no further clicks with my trackpad would be recognized. It helped to switch off the mouse.